# Theano is missing signal.conv module

Tags: python, theano

My theano doesn't have the `signal.conv` module

```
import theano.tensor.signal.conv
>>AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'conv'
```

My theano version is '0.7.0'. I tried to upgrade doing `pip install theano --upgrade` and it tells me that I am already up-to-date. How can I get the conv module?

PS: I even updated to the dev version by doing `sudo pip install --upgrade --no-deps git+git://github.com/Theano/Theano.git` and still no `signal.conv` !!

If I do `theano.tensor.signal.__file__` I get the path to the file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/signal/__init__.pyc` in the same folder I have the file conv.py and downsample.py I can sucessfuly call `theano.tensor.signal.downsample` but not `theano.tensor.signal.conv`

---- Installing on a Virtualenv ----

I tried to reproduce the error on a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv --no-site-packages myenv
cd myenv
source bin/activate
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install theano
python
import theano
theano.tensor.signal.conv
>>AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'conv'
```

I am on a Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits, python 2.7.6

Comment: I installed the 0.7.0 version of Theano just now, and that module imports fine for me. Does the result of `theano.tensor.signal.__file__` match where `pip` installed Theano to? Can you reproduce the problem with a virtualenv, and add to your question the list of commands that reproduces the problem?

Comment: did you try `import theano` and then `import theano.tensor.signal.conv` (`tensor` doesn't implicitly import `signal` or `signal.conv`)?

Comment: @JörnHees No I did not. And it worked ! thanks a lot, I guess I was confused on how import works

Comment: That's why you should always try the code you post in your question :) Even if you think you've already tried the "same thing" in another way. You might just find your answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

as written in the comment above, i think this is caused by `tensor` not implicitly importing `signal` or even `signal.conv`, hence you have to do the import yourself to use it:

```
In [1]: import theano

In [2]: theano.tensor
Out[2]: <module 'theano.tensor' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/__init__.pyc'>
```

As you can see importing `theano` also gets us the `theano.tensor` module, but as `tensor.__init__.py` doesn't import `signal` for example, the following does not work:

```
In [3]: theano.tensor.signal
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-53b46c46cb25> in <module>()
----> 1 theano.tensor.signal

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signal'

In [4]: theano.tensor.signal.conv
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-b2a3482abaed> in <module>()
----> 1 theano.tensor.signal.conv

AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'signal'
```

After importing the submodule it does:

```
In [5]: import theano.tensor.signal.conv

In [6]: theano.tensor.signal
Out[6]: <module 'theano.tensor.signal' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/signal/__init__.pyc'>

In [7]: theano.tensor.signal.conv
Out[7]: <module 'theano.tensor.signal.conv' from '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/theano/tensor/signal/conv.pyc'>
```

Comment: I can only award the bounty in 8 hours.. I will do it after